# Escape values in multiples DB raw select in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-query-builder

In my query I have something like:

```
->select('User.id', 'city', 'lat', 'lng', 'comment', 'Comments.created_at', 'disponibility',
        DB::raw("User.*, (count(Comments.user_id)) as note_count"),
        DB::raw("User.*, (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((:lat - lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(:lat * pi()/180) * COS(lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((:lng - lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))/0.621371192) as distance"),
        ["lat" => $lat, "lng" => $lng]
)
```

For a reason, it give me error that I don't know why

```
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Anyone can help me please?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is probably that you put your binding not as 2nd argument for `DB::raw` but as argument for `select` method.

Just try instead of above code:

```
->select('User.id', 'city', 'lat', 'lng', 'comment', 'Comments.created_at', 'disponibility',
        DB::raw("User.*, (count(Comments.user_id)) as note_count"),
        DB::raw("User.*, (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((:lat - lat) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS(:lat * pi()/180) * COS(lat * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((:lng - lng) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))/0.621371192) as distance", ["lat" => $lat, "lng" => $lng])
)
```